# How to talk about a class or meeting?

Tags: american-english, phrases

Is it correct to say:

> Will you run the meeting/class tomorrow?

When we want to ask if the meeting or class will be exacuted by tomorrow.

Is it the way American native speakers say it?

Also I want to know how to ask if they provide classes for something? For example I see an announcement about a jam for a dance club, and I want to ask if they also provide regular/weekly dance classes?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to know.

If you want to know if there will be a class, the most idiomatic way to ask would be:

> Is the class on tomorrow?

Asking "will you run the meeting" as you suggested might well be understood, but it could also sound like it is specifically directed to the person you are asking. You could get the answer "no, my colleague will run it".

That doesn't mean you can't use "you" to mean the business or organisation that the person represents - my suggestion to the second part of your question would be to ask "*do you have dance classes?*". It's just that 'running' the class does sound like you are asking about the person who is leading it, simply because it isn't the most idiomatic way to ask if a class, which is already scheduled, is going ahead.

Comment: My point for my first question is exactly what you said in your last sentence. For example last week somebody told me we will have a class/meeting on next week Wednesday, and today I want to ask him: "Will tomorrow's class/meeting goes ahead?". I mean would it be still available and it's not cancelled?

Comment: About my second question, when I use google translator, it suggests me "hold a class". But I don't know in native American English, do you also use hold a class to ask such a question: "Do you hold a dance class?" or it's just redundant?

Comment: @WDR To "hold" a class means to run an individual class, not regularly run a course of classes. Similarly, to "hold a meeting" means the same. You can say, for example, "we hold a meeting every monday". But you're not trying to ask a teacher or a lecturer if they are holding *a* class - you're asking the organisation in a more general way if they *have* such a class.